# Excel/ Numbers search for multiple occurrences

Tags: excel, search, apple-numbers

I have a CSV sheet with phone numbers and a bunch of unneeded text.

How do I go through the sheet and show each phone number along with the number of times it occurs in the list?

**For example:**

```
241-342-3242
345-412-4123
543-234-4322
345-412-4123
```

**Expected result:**

```
Number        |  Occurs
241-342-3242  |  1
345-412-4123  |  2
543-234-4322  |  1
```

---

**EDIT:**

The actual text is formatted as follows:

```
2  |  02/01  |  02:25 PM  |  555.123.4567  |  INCOMING  |  DT  |  5  |  0.00
3  |  02/01  |  12:58 PM  |  559.765.4321  |  FRESNO    |  DT  |  4  |  0.00
```

Comment: `COUNTIF()` should work, no?

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIF will do this.

If you assume that we are searching column A2:A100 contain the phone numbers, just place this in B2 and fill down:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$100,$B2)
```

Comment: It does sort of, but then I would have to manually enter every phone number in the B2 cell. instead of having a list with unique phone numbers and counts -- Updated question with format of text

Comment: You want to create a new list of numbers?

Comment: a list in which it counts the occurrences of the numbers listed in Column A.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a pivot table. Just use that one column as a source for the pivot table, and when placing the fields, drag it onto row area and also onto the values area.

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be to copy the tel numbers to a new sheet, remove duplicates then count from these values, something like this

```
Sub countTel()
Dim rng_list As Range
Dim frow As Long
Dim frow2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim sheetName As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet ''change this to sheet with your data in
sheetName = ws.Name

frow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ''finds number of rows
Set rng_list = ws.Range("d2:d" & frow) ''creates list of tel numbers
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
rng_list.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A1:A" & frow) ''copys to new sheet


ws2.Range("a1:a" & frow - 1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo ''removes duplicates so one of each value
frow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ''finds number of rows
ws2.Range("b1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & sheetName & "!$D$2:$D$" & frow & ",A1)" ''adds formula
ws2.Range("b1:b" & frow2).FillDown ''''adds formula to all rows

End Sub
```

depending on your data you might have to change columns and start rows.

Also if yo want to save this you will have to convert to xlsx as csv only allow 1 sheet